# How to use other Angular2 service inside an ngrx/Store reducer?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, redux, ngrx

New to both ngrx/Store and reducer. Basically, I have this reducer:

```js
import {StoreData, INITIAL_STORE_DATA} from "../store-data";
import {Action} from "@ngrx/store";
import {
  USER_THREADS_LOADED_ACTION, UserThreadsLoadedAction, SEND_NEW_MESSAGE_ACTION,
  SendNewMessageAction
} from "../actions";
import * as _ from "lodash";
import {Message} from "../../shared-vh/model/message";
import {ThreadsService} from "../../shared-vh/services/threads.service";

export function storeData(state: StoreData = INITIAL_STORE_DATA, action: Action): StoreData {


  switch (action.type) {

    case SEND_NEW_MESSAGE_ACTION:
      return handleSendNewMessageAction(state, action);

    default:
      return state
  }
}

function handleSendNewMessageAction(state:StoreData, action:SendNewMessageAction): StoreData {

  const newStoreData = _.cloneDeep(state);

  const currentThread = newStoreData.threads[action.payload.threadId];

  const newMessage: Message = {
    text: action.payload.text,
    threadId: action.payload.threadId,
    timestamp: new Date().getTime(),
    participantId: action.payload.participantId,
    id: [need a function from this service: ThreadsService]
  }

  currentThread.messageIds.push(newMessage.id);

  newStoreData.messages[newMessage.id] = newMessage;

  return newStoreData;
}
```

The problem is within the reducer function, I do not know how to inject an injectable service I created in a different file and use the function within it. The id part - I need to generate a firebase push ID using function like this.threadService.generateID() ...

But since this is a function, I do not have a constructor to use DI and I have no idea how to get functions within threadService!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There is no mechanism for injecting services into reducers. Reducers are supposed to be pure functions.

Instead, you should use [`ngrx/effects`](https://github.com/ngrx/effects) - which is the mechanism for implementing action side-effects. Effects listens for particular actions, perform some side-effect and then (optionally) emit further actions.

Typically, you would split your action into three: the request; the success response; and the error response. For example, you might use:

```ts
SEND_NEW_MESSAGE_REQ_ACTION
SEND_NEW_MESSAGE_RES_ACTION
SEND_NEW_MESSAGE_ERR_ACTION
```

And your effect would look something like this:

```ts
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Actions, Effect, toPayload } from "@ngrx/effects";
import { Action } from "@ngrx/store";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";

@Injectable()
export class ThreadEffects {

  constructor(
    private actions: Actions,
    private service: ThreadsService
  ) {}

  @Effect()
  sendNewMessage(): Observable<Action> {

    return this.actions
      .ofType(SEND_NEW_MESSAGE_REQ_ACTION)
      .map(toPayload)
      .map(payload => {
        try {
          return {
              type: SEND_NEW_MESSAGE_RES_ACTION,
              payload: {
                  id: service.someFunction(),
                  // ...
              }
          };
        } catch (error) {
          return {
              type: SEND_NEW_MESSAGE_ERR_ACTION
              payload: {
                error: error.toString(),
                // ...
              }
          };
        }
      });
  }
}
```

Rather than interacting with the service, your reducer would then be a pure function that would need only to handle the `SEND_NEW_MESSAGE_RES_ACTION` and `SEND_NEW_MESSAGE_ERR_ACTION` to do something appropriate with the success or error payloads.

Effects are observable-based, so incorporating synchronous, promise-based or observable-based services is straight forward.

There are some [effects](https://github.com/ngrx/example-app/tree/master/src/app/effects) in the `ngrx/example-app`.

*Regarding your queries in the comments:*

The `.map(toPayload)` is just for convinience. `toPayload` is an `ngrx` function that exists so it can be passed to `.map` to extract the action's `payload`, that's all.

Calling a service that's observable-based is straight-forward. Typically, you'd do something like this:

```ts
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import "rxjs/add/observable/of";
import "rxjs/add/operator/catch";
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";
import "rxjs/add/operator/switchMap";

@Effect()
sendNewMessage(): Observable<Action> {

  return this.actions
    .ofType(SEND_NEW_MESSAGE_REQ_ACTION)
    .map(toPayload)
    .switchMap(payload => service.someFunctionReturningObservable(payload)
      .map(result => {
        type: SEND_NEW_MESSAGE_RES_ACTION,
        payload: {
          id: result.id,
          // ...
        }
      })
      .catch(error => Observable.of({
        type: SEND_NEW_MESSAGE_ERR_ACTION
        payload: {
          error: error.toString(),
          // ...
        }
      }))
    );
}
```

Also, effects can be declared as functions returning `Observable<Action>` or as properties of type `Observable<Action>`. If you are looking at other examples, you are likely to come across both forms.

Comment: Thank you for such an good explanation. I'm new to effect/Ngrx. Your pattern is very helpful. Trying to clarify coupled things: 1. .map(toPayload) - is this where I call Firebae and get back an observable that's my newMessage object (observable, I don't have it yet)? Should this be a switchMap instead since it's an Action observable to a Firebase list observable? 2. SECOND .map(payload... which is I had the NewMessage object right? NOT an observable. So I can call another service to get the ID. What if the ID is also an observable? How will I change your code? Thank you!

Comment: I've updated the answer to address your further questions.

Comment: Thank you! Last question to clarify: So if the service.gettingId is observable based, you use switchMap BEFORE you mapping the result to RES and ERR action. If the service.gettingId is just synchronous function, you do it inside the RES payload, right? I love your pattern, just want to make sure I understand 100% so I can use it in my code.

Comment: Yeah, pretty much. If it's synchronous, you could make the service call anyplace inside the `map` in the first snippet - where you are mapping the payload to the resultant action.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much! Off topic here, you seem to know a lot of ngrx/store and ngrx/effect. Beside the official example, what other places you would recommend me to read up? Really want to change all my coding into reactive and store based. And all the docs out there are for the expert level readers (hard to wrap my mind around).

Comment: too bad. our tslint does not allow for console.log, so in a nativescript environment, there's no real good way to debug without injecting our debugging service...

Comment: What if I have a service full of pure functions which I don't want to keep in a global variable outside of angular?

Comment: Thanks, but can you inject a service in an @Effect?

Comment: How does a log service affect a pure function?

Answer (score 5):

After thinking a while about this I came up with this idea: What if I have a service full of pure functions which I don't want to keep in a global variable outside of angular like this:

```
export const fooBarService= {
    mapFooToBar: (foos: Foo[]): Bar[] => {
        let bars: Bar[];
        // Implementation here ...
        return bars;
    } 
}
```

I would like to have it as a service so I can easily pass it in the application without anybody freaking out that I don't use dependency injection:

```
@Injectable()
export class FooBarService{
    public mapFooToBar (foos: Foo[]): Bar[] {
        let bars: Bar[];
        // Implementation here ...
        return bars;
    } 
}
```

I can use `ReflectiveInjector` in order to get an instance of the service I need. Keep in mind that this injector is invoked before the main app is going live so it's really necessary to play nice and avoid keeping state in these services. And of course also because reducers really have to be pure (for your own sanity).

```
// <!> Play nice and use only services containing pure functions
var injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([FooBarService]);
var fooBarService= injector.get(FooBarService);

// Due to changes in ngrx4 we need to define our own action with payload
export interface PayloadAction extends Action {
    payload: any
}

/**
 * Foo bar reducer
 */
export function fooBarReducer(
    state: FooBarState = initialState.fooBar, 
    action: PayloadAction
) {
    switch (action.type) {

        case fooBarActions.GET_FOOS_SUCCESS:
            return Object.assign({}, state, <FooBarState>{
                foos: action.payload,
                // No effects used, all nicelly done in the reducer in one shot
                bars: fooBarService.mapFooToBar (action.payload) 

            });

        default:
            return state;
    }

}
```

Using this setup I can use three types of service `FooBarDataService`, `FooBarMapsService` and `FooBarLogicService`. Data service calls the webapi and provides observables from the state store with the results. Map service is used to map foos to bars and Logic service is used to add the business logic in a separate layer. This way I can have tiny controllers that are used only to glue objects together and serve them to the templates. Almost no logic in controllers. And as a final touch, the resolvers can provide the state store data in the routes thus abstracting away the state store completely.

More details about `ReflexiveInjector` [here](https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ReflectiveInjector-class.html).

Comment: Then your reducer is, by definition, no longer a pure function, as it depends upon external state - the service.

Comment: I tend to disagree with this observation. I stated twice that the services are suposed to have only pure functions. So you could consider them almost an external lib like underscore or whatever. I see no side effect. Only state that is resulting after the web api call. What if I had a web api call providing both foos and bars at once (or separate calls for foos and bars)? Than would bars still be considered a side effect? Cheers!

Comment: it would be nice if we could inject our debugging/logging services.... kinda sucks

Comment: Converting an Observable based store to an NgRx based one, I'm surprised reducers have to be in the global space and cannot be defined in a service. Now, I'm forced to take the hackway so as to use a pure utility function sitting in a service.

Comment: Would this approach though limit the utility of a service. I ran straight into this just recently. A component in an app I was working with made calls directly to localStorage. I did the right thing, created a localStorageService in the services lib, and implemented it. The follow up was to implement it everywhere in the app. Then I saw the reducers were calling localStorage. If I wanted to cache values in the service that were get/set in other areas of the app (pretty common thing to do), using this method, would I see those same values?

Comment: This all goes without saying, that I understand that reducers should not be tampering with external state this way. This should do what they do and dispatch actions, and the other stuff should be done in effects. This has always been a liability of the redux approach; excessive boilerplating (as mentioned above, the call/success/fail actions and related effects etc). I've never liked redux/ngrx/etc. for that reason, it's verbose beyond belief. But if you're going to use it, use it the way you're supposed to, bloviated boilerplate and all.